# Send JSONArray from android to php

Tags: php, android, json

I transferred a `JSONArray` from my android app to my php file and when I echo it on the php file it echo's back "Array" but I can't seem to access the contents of the array.

**Here is part of my php file:**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$orderJSON = urldecode($_POST['order']);
$orderJSON = json_decode($orderJSON,true);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password2, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo $orderJSON;
```

I cant seem to access the contents, they all return null, I used the following to encode the `JSONArray` on android.

```
String jsonPost = URLEncoder.encode("order","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(jsonArray.toString(),"UTF-8");
```

I have double check if the array has data before posting it through and it does display the loaded contents, even on the php file it echo's the contents when I comment out the `json_decode()` method

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($orderJSON);`?

Comment: If you do not show how you send the data to your php script we cannot tell what is ok in it. Or line one. Or line two and three. But not all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$orderJSON** is an array and you cannot use echo to show contents of an array in PHP. Use **print_r($orderJSON);** instead.

About how to access data in the array please refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... So how do i access the contents of that array? The methods i have used return null